# Devexpress xtraChart How to assign x and y values?

Tags: charts, devexpress

I have values in datasource and there is no problem with datasource. I have to assign X and Y values to the chart. Chart throws an error and says there is no column with named "TotalInboundArrivals".

```
ChartControl chart = new ChartControl();
chart.Location = new Point(38, 301);
chart.Size = new Size(789, 168);
Series series = new Series("Series1", ViewType.Bar);
chart.Series.Add(series);
series.DataSource = ds;
series.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
series.ArgumentDataMember = "TotalInboundArrivals"; //throws error here
series.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
series.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "StartTime" }); //throws error here 

((SideBySideBarSeriesView)series.View).ColorEach = true;
((XYDiagram)chart.Diagram).AxisY.Visible = true;
chart.Legend.Visible = true;
chart.Visible = true;
chart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
xtraTabPage1.Controls.Add(chart);
```

Where is my Problem? Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Have you went through [Series.DataSource Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/DevExpressXtraChartsSeries_DataSourcetopic). You are making the mistake of assigning DataSet as DataSource to series. Think about it, how could it search columns in Data Source. Try to assign `Ds.Tables["TableName"]` as the datasource.

Creating DataSource Table

```
private DataTable CreateChartData(int rowCount) {
            // Create an empty table.
            DataTable table = new DataTable("Table1");

            // Add two columns to the table.
            table.Columns.Add("Argument", typeof(Int32));
            table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));

            // Add data rows to the table.
            Random rnd = new Random();
            DataRow row = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                row = table.NewRow();
                row["Argument"] = i;
                row["Value"] = rnd.Next(100);
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

Specifying Series properties corresponding to datasource

```
Series series = new Series("Series1", ViewType.Bar);
            chart.Series.Add(series);

            // Generate a data table and bind the series to it.
            series.DataSource = CreateChartData(50);

            // Specify data members to bind the series.
            series.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
            series.ArgumentDataMember = "Argument";
            series.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
            series.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Value" });
```

Check the [Examples](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument2458) and go through the Creating `Charts -> Providing Data` section to better understand it.

[**Reference**](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q322957.aspx)

Hope this helps.